# swipe to delete javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, swipe

I am working on a function that will delete a div when you swipe it left...

Here is a div that I would like to delete when it is swiped:

```
<div class="listItem">Stuff here</div>
```

I have javascript to determine where on the page I have swiped by using the touchstart and touchend event listeners.

I have created a function called to delete the item:

```
function swipeLeft(){
     //delete item
}
```

I am determining where I swipe like this:

```
var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
dist = touchobj.pageX - startX
```

Now is it possible to delete the div with this information?

Comment: Check out this lib [swiped.js](https://github.com/mishk0/swiped) for implementation "swipe to delete". Maybe it will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you just calculate the deltas between the div's sizes and swipe distance.

Here is a good example for a generic swipe pattern detection:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml

Code:

```
function swipedetect(el, callback){

    var touchsurface = el,
    swipedir,
    startX,
    startY,
    distX,
    distY,
    threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
    restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
    allowedTime = 300, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
    elapsedTime,
    startTime,
    handleswipe = callback || function(swipedir){}

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        swipedir = 'none'
        dist = 0
        startX = touchobj.pageX
        startY = touchobj.pageY
        startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
    }, false)

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
        if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ // first condition for awipe met
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
                swipedir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates left swipe
            }
            else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
                swipedir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates up swipe
            }
        }
        handleswipe(swipedir)
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
}

//USAGE:
/*
var el = document.getElementById('someel')
swipedetect(el, function(swipedir){
    swipedir contains either "none", "left", "right", "top", or "down"
    if (swipedir =='left')
        alert('You just swiped left!')
})
*/
```

All you do is adjust the threshold if you need to. Once detected you just remove the div from the DOM.